# Cannot add file filename collides with an existing file perforce

Tags: perforce

I am trying to submit a CL to perforce but I am getting this error message

> Cannot add file '.../cfg_files/file1.cfg', filename collides with an
> existing file '.../cfg_files'

cfg_files is a soft link submitted earlier to another directory that I had in Peforce and the original directory had a file with the name file1.cfg. I am not sure what I did wrong to cause that issue or how to solve it. I have tried

```
p4 revert cfg_files/file1.cfg
```

output: cfg_files/file1.cfg - file(s) not opened on this client.

```
p4 shelve -c CL# cfg_files/file1.cfg
```

output:
Shelving files for change CL#.
cfg_files/file1.cfg - file(s) not opened in that changelist.
No files to shelve.

Any help to solve that issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the output actually coming back from Perforce with a `...`?  That would be unexpected.  It looks like your attempts to fix the issue are happening in the wrong directory -- an easy fix would be to just use the depot path from the error message.

Comment: No '...' is not coming from perforce, I just replaced that path with '...' in the question. I also made sure that I am working in the right directory.

Comment: You can't submit a file if it's not open, and from the error it sounds like the file isn't open.  (I suspect in actuality you've got a typo somewhere, but it's impossible to verify without seeing the real output.)

Comment: That's the real output Cannot add file '//dvt/v20/dev/main/test/gui/selenium_tests/playback/cfg_files/file1.cfg', filename collides with an existing file '//dvt/v20/dev/main/test/gui/selenium_tests/playback/cfg_files'.

Comment: You were right, I was executing the commands from the directory I had the original directory in and not the one with the soft link. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To revert the file so that it's no longer included in the pending changelist you're trying to submit, use the full path:

```
p4 revert //dvt/v20/dev/main/test/gui/selenium_tests/playback/cfg_files/file1.cfg
```

If you instead want to delete the `cfg_files` symlink that conflicts with the directory you're trying to add, do:

```
p4 delete //dvt/v20/dev/main/test/gui/selenium_tests/playback/cfg_files
```